# Derivation of the Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation in stochastic control

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, optimal-control, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I am reading the book [Continuous-time Stochastic Control and Optimization by Huyen Pham](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540894995), and I am stuck on the derivation of the Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation (§3.4.1 page 42).

**My question is: why is $\mathbb{E}M_h=0$ in ($\star$)?**

Specifically (notations are defined below), for $a$ fixed, after applying Itô's formula, we have
$$v(t+h, X_{t+h}^{t,x})=v(t,x)+\int_{t}^{t+h}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+\mathcal{L}^a v\right)(s,X_s^{t,x})\mathrm d s + \underbrace{\int_{t}^{t+h}\nabla_xv(s,X_s^{t,x})\sigma(X_s^{t,x},a)\mathrm dW_s}_{M_h} \tag{$\star$}$$
where the term $M_h$ is a local martingale. I tried (and failed) to show that $M$ is a true martingale by two approaches:

1. Show that $\mathbb{E}\int_0^h\langle M, M\rangle_s \mathrm ds<\infty$. However, I don't see how to bind the term in $\nabla_xv(s,X^{t,x}_s)$.
2. Use a localization step. The problem is that I then neeed some sort of dominated integrability condition on $v$ to use the dominated convergence theorem afterwards, and I don't think that such a condition holds without further assumptions on $v$ (e.g., quadratic growth).

Am I missing something? Is this more of a heuristic derivation (the § is titled "formal derivation")?

**Some context.** $v$ is the value function, which we assume to be smooth, $f:(t,x,a)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is an integrable functional objective and $X^{t,x}_s$ is the unique strong solution to the SDE
$$\mathrm d X_s = b(X_s,a)\mathrm ds+\sigma(X_s,a)\mathrm dW_s$$
started at $x$ at time $t$, where $b$ and $\sigma$ satisfy a uniform Lipschitz condition.

Comment: I am stuck on exactly the same step. Were you able to find an explanation to it?